# NUnit Throws.Nothing.After( , ) test fails first time

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have an NUnit test that sometimes throws an exception at the start so I'm wanting to wrap this in a timeout with a delay and interval using the `.After` Constraint.

This is not the exact code but it's an example of what I'm talking about and trying to achive.

```
[Test]
public void ThrowsNothingAfterTest()
{
    var i = 0;
    Assert.That(() =>
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        i++;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }, Throws.Nothing.After(1000, 100));
}
```

I'd assume that the above test would fail first time then pass the time after but it only runs once and fails.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to achieve here? Your test does not make much sense.

Comment: I've got a service that spins up within a `[SetUpFixture]` and it takes a while to initiate. So I'm wanting to call a webservice that the service is exposing and then test it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`After` may be functionally inconsistent with `Throws.Nothing`. We should check it out and probably figure out a way to make it syntactically impossible.

What you are saying with the syntax you use is: keep trying this call every 100 ms until it doesn't throw, up to a maximum of 1000ms (10 times). This is harmless for your example but would not be desirable in many cases. That's why I would lean toward making it non-compilable rather than making it work. :-(

If you can write code to return true when your service is initialized, then you can simply use

```
Assert.That(() => IsServiceUpAndRunning(),
            After(1).Seconds.PollEvery(10).Milliseconds);
```

If an exception is thrown, just catch it in the method and return false.

Comment: Would be nice if it just worked like the `Is` but this is a fairly acceptable workaround. Thanks

Comment: Wow, this answer finally led me to understand that After(100).PollEvery(2) does not wait 100ms then poll every 2ms forever.  This feels like a Fluent-design bug.  With how it is programmed to work it should be written as .PollEvery(2).Timeout(100)